# Get element's ng-model value in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is a fictional example, I have a huge template with multiple forms and I want to mark the sections which have touched inputs.

```
<section my-directive>
  <form name="user">
    <input type="text" ng-model="someCtrlAlias.data.firstname">
    <input type="text" ng-model="someCtrlAlias.data.lastname">
  </form>
</section>

<section my-directive>
  <form name="address">
    <input type="text" ng-model="someCtrlAlias.data.street">
    <input type="text" ng-model="someCtrlAlias.data.zipcode">
  </form>
</section>
```

I want to check each input field if it has been touched. Basically what $dirty does, but the problem is that the user can save and continue later, so $dirty disappears. I don't want to separate the subform into data1.firstname, data2.street because then I need to remove these fields later when saving them the database.

I've tried this:

```
angular.forEach element.find('input'), (input) ->
  $input = angular.element(input)
  name = $input.attr('name')
  console.log name, "=>", $input.attr('ng-model')
```

But `$input.attr('ng-model')` just shows me the name of the assigned model. I could pass the entire Object into the directive and access the property from there e.g. `myModel[$input.attr('ng-model').replace("myController.", "")]` but this seems inefficient.

Comment: What does your directive contain? Since it's on the `form` element, it has access to the [`FormController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController), which has methods for `$setDirty()` and `$setPristine()`. You can also get its elements' ng-models by using `form[inputName]`.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the scope of the form:

```
$form = element.find('form')
formName = $form.attr('name')
formScope = $form.scope()[$form.attr('name')]
```

All angular keys have a `$` the rest seems to be only my models:

```
keys = Object.keys(formScope).filter( (key)-> return key.indexOf('$') == -1 ).filter( (key)-> return formScope[key].$modelValue? )
if keys.length > 0
  console.log "#{formName} is set dirty"
  formScope.$setDirty(true)
```